# QuickSort in Java, for high number of elements

Tags: java, eclipse, sorting, time, quicksort

I need some help. I've implemented QuickSort in Java and now I'm testing the required time to work with 50.000 to 15.000.000 elements. The problem is that it's taking so long. For example:

```
50.000 Elements, 38 seconds.
100.000 Elements, 230 seconds.
250.000 Elements, I'm still waiting (around 8 minutes)
```

Is this okay? Here's my code:

```
/* Clase que implementa el QuickSort */
public class QuickSort {
    private static final int corte = 3;
    private int i, j;

    public void ordenar(Comparable[] a, int izquierda, int derecha) {

        if (izquierda + corte <= derecha) {

            Comparable pivote = mediana(a, izquierda, derecha);

            i = izquierda;
            j = derecha - 1;

            for (;;) {
                while (a[++i].compareTo(pivote) < 0) {
                }
                while (a[--j].compareTo(pivote) > 0) {
                }
                if (i < j) {
                    intercambiar(a, i, j);
                } else {
                    break;
                }

                intercambiar(a, i, derecha - 1);
            }

            ordenar(a, izquierda, i - 1);
            ordenar(a, i + 1, derecha);

        } else {

            InsertSort(a);
        }
    }

    private static Comparable mediana(Comparable[] a, int izquierda, int derecha) {
        int centro = (izquierda + derecha) / 2;

        if (a[centro].compareTo(a[izquierda]) < 0) {
            intercambiar(a, izquierda, centro);
        }

        if (a[derecha].compareTo(a[izquierda]) < 0) {
            intercambiar(a, izquierda, derecha);
        }

        if (a[derecha].compareTo(a[centro]) < 0) {
            intercambiar(a, centro, derecha);
        }

        intercambiar(a, centro, derecha - 1);
        return a[derecha - 1];

    }

    private static void intercambiar(Comparable[] arreglo, int a, int b) {
        Comparable temporal;
        temporal = arreglo[a];
        arreglo[a] = arreglo[b];
        arreglo[b] = temporal;

    }

    private void InsertSort(Comparable[] lista) {

        for (int i = 1; i < lista.length; i++) {
            Comparable auxiliar = lista[i];
            int j = i - 1;

            while (j >= 0 && lista[j].compareTo(auxiliar) > 0) {

                lista[j + 1] = lista[j];
                j = j - 1;

            }

            lista[j + 1] = auxiliar;

        }
    }
}



public class Test {

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        long tInicial = 0;
        long tFinal = 0;
        long tRes = 0;
        int tam = 250000;

        Arreglo B = new Arreglo (tam);

        System.out.print("Prueba de Tiempo:");
        B.cargarArreglo();
        tInicial = System.currentTimeMillis();
        B.ordenarArreglo();
        tFinal = System.currentTimeMillis();

        tRes = tFinal - tInicial;
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Tiempo Transcurrido (ms): " + tRes + " para " + tam + " elementos.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `InsertSort(a);` sort the whole array? Why would you want to sort the whole array as base case for the quicksort recursion?

Comment: Greaaat! That was my mistake! Thank you! A LOT! Now, 250.000 Elements takes 328 ms to finish. Thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The runtime of quicksort is (average) O(n log n) or (worstcase) O(n^2). This means the runtime for 50.000 is 50.000 * 10.819778284410283 ~ 540000. For 250.000 the runtime would be: 250.000 * 12.429216196844383 ~ 3.100.000. Due to this, the runtime would for 250.000 would be ~6x the runtime of 50.000. Another factor would be the memorymanagement. The factor from 50.000 to 250.000 elements actually is: ~12.63. This is still ok considering the worstcase of O(n^2).